# glReadPixels returning incorrect values

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to implement picking via following an opengl tutorial, I have a mesh with 6000 vertices and I wish to pick particular ones; I have chosen to do by redering uniquely coloured boxes at each vertex point, read the pixel on my mouse click at that point and that should return to me the ID of the closest vertex. The background is rendered as white so if I miss I get nothing.

However I have a problem, it only works most of the time; there are certain areas that if I click there I get white returned even though its clearly a vertex, and when rendering the colorized scene clearly has a redish box at the point I clicked.

Then there are white areas near the mesh, to the bottom left and at some random point away from it, returns me a hit.

I do not understand at all why this is happening, it should work.

```
void Display() {
Controls->setVector(indexed_vertices);


if (Controls->getPicking()) {
    // Clear the screen in white
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for ( int i=0; i< indexed_vertices.size(); i++) {
        // use shaders
        glUseProgram(pickingProgramID);
        // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
        GLuint PickingMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(pickingProgramID, "MVP");

        glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(orientations);
        glm::mat4 btTranslationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), indexed_vertices[i]);
        glm::mat4 myModelMatrix = ModelMatrix * Controls->getTranslationMatrix() * Controls->getRotationMatrix() * btTranslationMatrix;
        MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * myModelMatrix;
        Controls->setCntrlsViewMatrix(ViewMatrix);
        Controls->setCntrlsProjectionMatrix(ProjectionMatrix);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(PickingMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);


        // Convert "i", the integer mesh ID, into an RGB color
        int r = (i & 0x000000FF) >>  0;
        int g = (i & 0x0000FF00) >>  8;
        int b = (i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;

        // OpenGL expects colors to be in [0,1], so divide by 255.
        glUniform4f(pickingColorID, r/255.0f, g/255.0f, b/255.0f, 1.0f);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gvertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Index buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

        // Draw the triangles !
        glDrawElements(
            GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
            indices.size(),    // count
            GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,   // type
            (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
        );
        // OpenGL expects colors to be in [0,1], so divide by 255.

    }
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glFlush();
    glFinish(); 


    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Read the pixel at the center of the screen.
    // You can also use glfwGetMousePos().
    // Ultra-mega-over slow too, even for 1 pixel, 
    // because the framebuffer is on the GPU.
    unsigned char data[4];
    glReadPixels(Controls->get_mx_cur(), Controls->get_my_cur(),1,1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    std::cout << "MX: " << Controls->get_mx_cur() << " MY: " << Controls->get_my_cur() << std::endl;

    // Convert the color back to an integer ID
    int pickedID = 
        data[0] + 
        data[1] * 256 +
        data[2] * 256*256;

    //std::cout << std::hex << pickedID << std::dec<<std::endl;
    if (pickedID == 0x00ffffff) { // Full white, must be the background !
        printf("Miss\n");
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "mesh " << pickedID << std::endl;
    }

    // Uncomment these lines to see the picking shader in effect
    glutSwapBuffers();
    skip = true;
    Controls->setPicking(false);
}
if (!skip) {
// White background
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glUseProgram(ShaderIDs[0]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);


glm::mat4 myModelMatrix = ModelMatrix * Controls->getTranslationMatrix() * Controls->getRotationMatrix();
MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * myModelMatrix;

// The inverse transpose of the View Model Matrix will re-normalize the normals if there's
// been any scaling. Otherwise you don't need it.
glm::mat3 NormalMatrix = glm::mat3( glm::transpose(glm::inverse(ViewMatrix * myModelMatrix)));

Controls->setCntrlsViewMatrix(ViewMatrix);
Controls->setCntrlsProjectionMatrix(ProjectionMatrix);

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &myModelMatrix[0][0]);
    // Notice we're passing a 3 by 3 matrix here.
glUniformMatrix3fv(NormalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix[0][0]);
glUniform3f(CameraID, cameraLoc.x, cameraLoc.y, cameraLoc.z);
glUniform3f(LightPosID, lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);

// VBO buffer: vertices
// 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,                  // attribute
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    0,                  // stride
    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

// 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    1,                                // attribute
    2,                                // size
    GL_FLOAT,                         // type
    GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
    0,                                // stride
    (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

// 2rd attribute buffer : normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    2,                                // attribute
    3,                                // size
    GL_FLOAT,                         // type
    GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
    0,                                // stride
    (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

// Index buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

if ( Controls->getRenderingMode() == 0 ) {
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    //glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
} 
else if (Controls->getRenderingMode() == 1 ) {

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glUseProgram(ShaderIDs[1]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &myModelMatrix[0][0]);
        // Notice we're passing a 3 by 3 matrix here.
    glUniformMatrix3fv(NormalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniform3f(CameraID, cameraLoc.x, cameraLoc.y, cameraLoc.z);
    glUniform3f(LightPosID, lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);
} 
else if (Controls->getRenderingMode() == 2 ) {
    glUseProgram(ShaderIDs[1]);
    // 
    glm::mat4 MyOffsetMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.025,1.025,1.025));
    MyOffsetMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 myModelMatrix2 = ModelMatrix * Controls->getTranslationMatrix() * 
        Controls->getRotationMatrix()*MyOffsetMatrix;
    glm::mat3 NormalMatrix2 = glm::mat3( glm::transpose(glm::inverse(ViewMatrix * 
        myModelMatrix2)));

    glm::mat4 MVP2 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * myModelMatrix2;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP2[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &myModelMatrix2[0][0]);
        // Notice we're passing a 3 by 3 matrix here.
    glUniformMatrix3fv(NormalMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix2[0][0]);
    glUniform3f(CameraID, cameraLoc.x, cameraLoc.y, cameraLoc.z);
    glUniform3f(LightPosID, lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);


    // The rest is exactly the same as the first object

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // 3rd attribute buffer : normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // Index buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    // Draw the triangles !
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPolygonOffset(2.0f, 2.0f);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    //glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    glUseProgram(ShaderIDs[0]);
}
//glUseProgram(ShaderIDs[1]);
// Draw the triangles !
glDrawElements(
    GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
    indices.size(),    // count
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,   // type
    (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
    );

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you already check if it might be a y-inversion problem? The coordinate system used by the window system, which is the coordinate system of your mouse coordinates, often has the opposite y-direction from the OpenGL coordinate system.

Comment: Well I mean, the little cubes are all in the right spots and in the tutorial code it was originally just the center of the screen so 1024/2 and 756/2 and that worked as far as I could tell. I think that isn't the problem as putting the y value as negative just returns the same value for every pixel.

Comment: Woops, did my math wrong there, I instead tried it as "abs(curr_my - height)" to invert it and that SEEMS to work now; but I still have the problem that the ID's returned are occassionally insane; such as 4214221 and 12567781; I suspect how pickID works is broken for large values.

Comment: [Edit: This was in response to previous comment.] Not sure if we're talking about the same thing. If it's a problem with y-inversion, you would have to change the second argument to `glReadPixels` to `WindowHeight - Controls->get_my_cur()`, where `WindowHeight` is the current height of your window in pixels.

Comment: Yes that's what I just did (although slightly backwards!) and it does seem to work; so now I need to figure out why I am getting such outrageous values: int pickedID = 
        data[0] + 
        data[1] * 256 +
        data[2] * 256*256; returns to me large values when I want between 0 and 6600 right?

Comment: @RaenirSalazar: You will get "insane" values if you use multisampling. I sincerely doubt that's your issue here, but anytime rasterization uses interpolation this technique will not work right. That could mean interpolating the color across vertices (also not an issue, since you are using a uniform to pass the color), averaging sampled color for anti-aliasing, etc. You do sometimes have to consider byte-order when you twiddle the RGBA pixels this way. Does this issue happen for any object with an ID > 255?

Comment: No I think it seems to happen when I'm clicking somewhere where there's two or more cubes very close together, maybe its confused which one is which? I was multisampling before, I'll try turning it off. Otherwise it works fine for 99% of them.

Comment: Oh, really? Yeah, you definitely need to disable multisample rasterization before using this technique. Fortunately if you have a multisampled framebuffer you don't have to draw into a different buffer, you can toggle it on/off with `glDisable (GL_MULTISAMPLE)`.

Comment: Turning off multisampling didn't resolve it; its more common when I'm zoomed out as opposed to when I'm zooming in, perhaps a quick fix is to reject any values larger than the total number of vertices; where this technique worked best was when the boxes being clicked were large meshes in of themselves; while these boxes are really small, the color seems to be done in the fragment shader, would that be interpolating it in edge cases?

Comment: I just re-read your question... it seems you are trying to draw some squares (or cubes, not sure) centered at the vertices of your object and those are what you are colorizing and trying to pick. You might actually consider using `GL_POINTS` for this instead, you are less likely to run into sub-pixel issues with them. Of course, you still need to disable multisample rasterization if you use them, or they will turn into smoothed circles instead of flat squares.

Comment: I figure you use that `pickingColorID` uniform in your fragment shader, and assign it directly to the output color? There shouldn't be any interpolation in that case. Even if there were interpolation for some reasons, it wouldn't explain that you get values that are completely out of range.

Comment: BTW, I don't think this will help you with the immediate problem, but I would initialize the values before calling `glReadPixels`, (`unsigned char data[4] = {'\0'};`). That way, if `glReadPixels` fails for any reason, you still have well defined values.

Comment: GL_POINTS? Is that immediate mode? As I'm trying to stick to Modern Opengl, with the caveat I'm investigating implementations of picking that are applicable to other situations. @Reto: Yeah pickingColorId is the uniform in the fragment and is directly being outputted. I did some more testing and I can more easily gaurantee an out of range value picking at the edges of squares on the outer edge of the mesh. http://imgur.com/MQ0H17J link for an example.

Comment: Are you sure that multisampling is completely disabled? Zooming in on that image, the edges of the cubes look blurry to me.

Comment: @RaenirSalazar: No, `GL_POINTS` is not immediate mode. It is a primitive type that allows you to render what effectively works out to be a screen-aligned quad (two triangles) using a single point instead of 4-6 separate vertices. The most useful property it offers in the current context is that if anti-aliasing is enabled, you will know it immediately because the points will show up as circles instead of squares. It may also improve performance by requiring you to define 1/4 - 1/6 as few points.

Comment: I'll try specifically using glDisable, maybe thats it.

Comment: glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) doesn't resolve it. :(

Comment: Alrighty I'm pretty sure the problem was the multisampling, I forgot I had glut init my display mode as multisampling and removing that seems to have fixed it, not a single crazy value!

Comment: Please also accept your answer so this question does not show up as unanswered. Thanks!

Comment: I have another day before I can :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was two-fold: Crazy numbers returned is a result of improper multisampling enabled when I wanted specific colour values (how to have my cake and eat it might need a bit of work but right now I don't care), and secondly because glReadPixels() inverts the Y axis and needed to do Height - Current_Mouse_Position for the Y value.

Perhaps glPoints would be faster means of doing what I'm doing, I'll need to look into it.